# Plotly: How to avoid grouping of x and y categories using go.Heatmap?

Tags: python, plotly

Hi I want to make a Heatmap using Plotly, like this:

https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1594s6eo3VfxRXrS-2asrGeiFAT-08G-w

The problem is that Plotly indexes x columns. The same column names cause a problem in my code.

https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1_KqOzzoikoKHd8TMNP20T4hDfy03KD8G

I want to make my x-axis columns display “T,G,G,G,A”, but they currently display as “T,G,A”.

How do I make my x-column display “T,G,G,G,A”?

My code is as follows:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import numpy as np
z = np.random.rand(4,5)
y = ['A','C','G','T']
x = ['T', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'A']
fig = go.Figure(
    data = go.Heatmap(z=z, y=y,x=x)
)

fig.show()
```

Comment: Please re-write your question for clarity (I don't understand the result you're after); and attach the images properly.  External links can pose security risks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `y=y` and `x=x` from `go.Heatmap`, specify `tickmode`, `tickvals` and `ticktext` like this:

```
fig.update_yaxes(tickmode = 'array',
                 tickvals = np.arange(0, len(y)),
                 ticktext= y)
```

And you'll get:

[image]

**Complete code:**

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import numpy as np
z = np.random.rand(4,5)
y = ['A','C','G','T']
x = ['T', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'A']

fig = go.Figure(
    data = go.Heatmap(z=z)
)

fig.update_yaxes(tickmode = 'array',
                 tickvals = np.arange(0, len(y)),
                 ticktext= y)

fig.update_xaxes(tickmode = 'array',
                 tickvals = np.arange(0, len(x)),
                 ticktext= x,
                 side = 'top')
```

If anything is unclear then let me know and we can get into the details.

Comment: Oh! My! God! You solved my problem! I have not solved this problem for a week. Thanks very much!

Comment: Do you know how to put the x-axis label up? :)

Comment: @dwchoo Just add `side='top'` in `fig.update_xaxes()`. I included it in the answer